# MySQL: Delete rows that contain a specific parameter and are older then a day

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, cron

I'm creating a login system for my website, with mysql. It works on a subscription based system. How would I remove all rows with the parameter "premium" equal to "1 DAY", if it's older then a day. I'm trying to run a command like this, in a cron job, that runs once a day. I would duplicate this for rows that have the parameter "premium" = "1 WEEK", etc.

Thanks,

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: Also please note that `1 day` could mean either 24-hour period or one calendar day (so when you purchase 1 day premium at 23:15, it will expire 45 minutes after buying). With calendar days you also run into a problem with time-zones.

Comment: Instead of storing `"1 DAY"` or `"1 WEEK"` in a "premium" field you can store an "expires at" timestamp. Set it appropriately when somebody buys a subscription and look for records where this value is earlier than the current time when you run your cleanup job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
delete t from loginsystem t
    where premium = '1 DAY' and created_at < now() - interval 1 day;
```